# Adding arraylist using a class to an array adapter

Tags: java, class, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add my information from an arraylist that is using a class, and adding the information to an array adapter in a list view. I'm trying to add the first name from this array.

How am I able to do that?

I have this separate class (not sure if the toString is correct):

```
public class PersonClass {

final private String firstName;
final private String lastName;
final private String birthday;
final private int personPic;

private PersonClass(String fName, String lName, String bDay, int pic) {

    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    birthday = bDay;
    personPic = pic;

}

public String toString() {
    return firstName+" "+lastName+" "+birthday+" "+personPic;
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    // Information for each person using the PersonClass
    PersonClass person1 = new PersonClass("first name", "last name", "01/01/2000", R.drawable.pic1); 
    // ..... up to 10... 


    // ArrayList
    final ArrayList<PersonClass> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Add person data to array list
    personList.add(person1);
    personList.add(person2);
    personList.add(person3);
    personList.add(person4);
    personList.add(person5);
    personList.add(person6);
    personList.add(person7);
    personList.add(person8);
    personList.add(person9);
    personList.add(person10);

  }

}
```

This is my array adapter.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAd = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,???);
```

I can't just add the arraylist name to the adapter because the array has a class adding the information to it. But I just want to show the first name of the array on the list view.

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to achieve here?

Comment: I'm adding a person with some information to an array list. From this list I need to get the first name and add this to a list view. I have the code for the adapter:ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAd = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ??? ); ... but this is as far as I go, I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: I have posted my answer let me know if you looking for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Person {
    private String firstName;

    //Might be more fields

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Person(String firstName) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}

public class SO1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        //Either you can directly add first name in adaptor
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            personList.add(new Person("Name "+i));
        }

        //If you have list than you have to iterate it and add first name
        List<String> adaptorList = new ArrayList<String>();
        personList.forEach( p -> adaptorList.add(p.getFirstName()));

        System.out.println(adaptorList);
    }

}
```

Comment: This was perfect. That's what I needed to get the strings. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Write a getter for the name. Member variables are private in order to access them with so called getter and setter Methods. Therefore you'd want the `getFirstName()` Method in your PersonClass.

```
public String getFirstName()
{
return firstName;
}
```

In your main

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();

nameList.add(person1.getFirstName());
```